# extjs combo drop list does not adapt to new data

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm loading data in a combo with data from a dummy store in the case the original stor is empty. SO the combo is actually already bound to an empty store, and I'm doing something like:

```
combo.store.loadData([dummy]);
```

where dummy is a single model I want to load. Combo feel the change, but the drop list is still almost zero size. I can pick the item inside bi clicking a single pixel as in the image below:

[image]
This is the reason I say combo feel the new datastore. How can I force the drop list to contain the new item(s) ?

Comment: What is model config and combo config. Especially, do valueField and displayField match model field names?

Comment: @Saky they match, actually when you select the 'pixel' the correct item is display in the combo.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was more subtle, the model `dummy` was created as below:

```
var dummy = Ext.ModelManager.create({
                    id: 0,
                    code: null,
                    description: '< my description>',
                    ranking:0
                }, 'MyApp.model.MyModel');
```

please nothe there is a couple of `'<' '>'`  in the description, that **it is not html encoded by the framework** ( I guessed it was, I think it should, but it is just an opinion ) this yield a bad html rendering that produce the nasty effect shown in the question.